# How do I set it so Apple Notes checklist items don't move when completed?

Tags: ios, notes.app

Googled it, can't find out how to do it. Seems like I saw a setting dialog pop up once.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

Settings > Notes > Sort Checked Items > Manually

[image]